# Speech recognition on iOS 9 swift 2

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, speech

Is speech recognition supported natively on iOS 9? If so, how can I implement it? I have tied using NSSpeechRecognizer() and it is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

Look into third party api's, there are many good ones out there, mashape has a great collection, but I preferably use Google's Web Speech Api because of Google's great free plan, and the quick server response.

Answer (score 1):

There's the `Speech` framework in **iOS 10**.

Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/reference/speech